# How do you add lint rule exceptions for java modules / relative paths in Android?

Tags: android, android-lint

I have an Android project that has the typical `myproject/app/` directory along with another separate java module `myproject/mymodule/`.

How do I add exceptions for `mymodule`? Using relative paths in app/lint.xml doesn't seem to work.

```
<issue id="RxLeakedSubscription">
    <ignore path="../mymodule/src/test/" />
</issue>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new lint.xml in the root of your module, and it'll be picked up (in this case create a new file `myproject/mymodule/lint.xml`)

```
<issue id="RxLeakedSubscription">
    <ignore path="src/test/" />
</issue>
```